# cordova, visual studio and frontend

Tags: cordova, user-interface, javascript-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I want to start mobile app development for a long time now. Made researches and reading a lot. Everytime i get confused which way to go.

Obj-C or swift (now i decided cant be bothered with obj-c and swift after a few tries.

Sencha is a good alternative but really frustrated with (lack of)ide. I dont want to pay for ide since i just do it as a hobby.

That brings me to apache cordova, and vs community arrived just in time. Now reading and searching for this alternative, seems good so far, except user interface part.

Here is my question, i dont yet to see enough samples or resources how i implement user interface. As i understand there are some alternatives like ionic, but would like to hear opinions, alternatives and experiences you people have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own user interface. It's all built in HTML and CSS.
Ionic is a framework for people who don't want to spend a lot of time building up an user interface, it's not a requirement. I'm using Kendo UI for the user interface combined with a few CSS changes and self written touch gestures.

Comment: Thanks. As far as i know Kendo is not free nor open source, at that point i am hesitant to spend money on a hobby project with my level of knowledge on mobile development. Will look further into ionic (unfortunately on beta) and jQueryMobile.

Comment: Big part of Kendo UI is open source and free to use. Mobile widgets are included in the free version. [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core) is what you need then.

Answer (score 0):

For quick apps or proof-of-concepts, I use jQueryMobile, and like its ajax navigation for single-page app.  I also use twitter bootstrap.  Both give you a start for laying out your app in responsive way to handle phone and tablet, portrait and landscape.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will give both a try.